# Python Selenium: element is not reachable by keyboard - how to resolve? Related to WCAG standard?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to log into a website using Selenium and Python 3.8.1 in Windows, here's my code up to the point where I get stuck:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.25)

driver.get('https://www.awebsite.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('userLogin')
elem.send_keys('chuu@blockberry.com')
```

My error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="ft_username" name="userLogin" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I've tried selecting using xpath and id instead of name and the result is the same.

While trying to figure this out, I tried in Firefox "inspect accessibilty properties" just to see what it did and noticed two warnings for the field where I'm trying to enter text:

```
Does not meet WCAG standards for keyboard accessibility 
Does not meet WCAG standards for text alternative
```

This would seem to be related somehow, but I don't know what it means or how to use this information to resolve the issue.  I guess if I were the site developer I could try to make it meet WCAG standards, but I'm a user who is stuck with this site the way it is, so how do I get around this issue in Python?

Comment: Was fine when I used css selector from (.login-form > div:nth-child(2) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(2)) and sent the keys.

Comment: This element or section you are trying to reach - could be inside the frame. Try to switch to the frame and then reach the element.

Comment: @arundeepchohan this worked, thank you!

Comment: @Villa_7 I couldn't make this solution work, because I couldn't find an iframe id in the source code to switch to on this page.

Comment: Accept the answer so it closes.

Comment: Before I do, I'd love to know why this works and the other things didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css selector from (.login-form > div:nth-child(2) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > 
   input:nth-child(2)

The element was not reacheable so use the css selector above.